# Compute norm of linear operator and prove that it cannot be obtained.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let us define linear operator $\Phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan((n+1)^2)x_{2n} \ $   in $\ \mathcal{l^1}$. Find its norm and prove that it cannot be attained.

For the first part I want to show that the operator is bounded.
\begin{align*}
|\Phi(x)| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan((n+1)^2)x_{2n}\right| & \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\arctan((n+1)^2)x_{2n}| \\
& \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\arctan((n+1)^2)||x_{2n}| \\
& \le \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{2n}| \\
& \le \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}| \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}\|x\|_{1}.
\end{align*}

However I have no idea how to show that there is no element such that equality holds in the above inequality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a full answer, you have yet to show $\| \Phi ‖ = \pi/2$. Consider the 'standard basis vectors' to finish this part of the question.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be a variable or a function? What is $x_n$?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson it's a sequence $ x = (x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ in $\ell^1$, i.e $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n| < \infty$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show it can't be attained, suppose we had some $x=\{x(n)\}_{n\ge 0}$ satisfying $\|x‖ = 1$ and attaining $‖ \Phi x‖ = \pi /2$. Suppose without loss that there is a positive component at position $k$, say $x(k)>0$; it is not hard to see that all components of $x$ must have the same sign by a similar argument to the below.

If there was any component $j>k$ with $x(k) > x(j)$, then we can maintain $\|x‖=1$ while switching the values at $k$ and $j$, while giving us a strictly bigger value of $\|\Phi x\|$. Since we assumed $x$ attains the sup, this is impossible and thus $x$ is a non-decreasing sequence of positive numbers. It is absurd that such a sequence is in $\ell^1$, which proves the result.

Comment: More generally, suppose $\Phi(x)=\sum_na_nx_n$.  Then $\Phi$ obtains its supremum if and only if there is some $k$ such that $|a_k|=\sup_n|a_n|$